# How to extract the synonyms of a specific individual from the whole Ontology?

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I am implementing an ontology in Eclipse with jena.I am trying to fetch the synonyms of an individual from whole ontology.

How i will get all the synonyms of a specific individual from whole ontology irrespective of the class.

```
 static final String inputFileName = "http://word.owl";
OntModel inf = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
        InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
        inf.read(in, "");       
        ExtendedIterator classes = inf.listClasses();
        while(classes.hasNext())
        {
            OntClass obj = (OntClass) classes.next();
            String className = obj.getLocalName().toString();
            System.out.println("Class Name : "+className);                         
        }   
        ExtendedIterator instances = inf.listIndividuals();
        while(instances.hasNext())
        {
            Individual ind = (Individual) instances.next();
            String indName = ind.getLocalName().toString();
            System.out.println("Individual Name : "+indName);                          
        }    

    ExtendedIterator property = inf.listDatatypeProperties();
   while(property.hasNext())
   {
       DatatypeProperty prop = (DatatypeProperty) property.next();
        String propName = prop.getLocalName().toString();
        System.out.println("Data Propties Name : "+propName);                           
    }
    ExtendedIterator property1 = inf.listObjectProperties();
    while(property1.hasNext())
    {
       ObjectProperty prop = (ObjectProperty) property1.next();
      String propName = prop.getLocalName().toString();
     System.out.println("Object Propties Name : "+propName);                           
}

    ObjectProperty isSynonymOf = inf.getObjectProperty("http://www.../Word#isSynonymOf"); 

    System.out.println("Individuals having isSynonymOf Proterty:");

    ExtendedIterator individuals1 = inf.listIndividuals();
    while(individuals1.hasNext())
    {
        Individual ind = (Individual) individuals1.next();
        if(ind.getProperty(isSynonymOf) != null)
       {
           String indName = ind.getLocalName().toString();
           System.out.println(indName);
       }


       }
}
```

Problem :when i will enter an individual for example *software*
It should give me all the synonyms as
 - Software
 - Software Architecture 
 - Software design 
 - Program

This is my OWL file

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Word#"
  xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Word"
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">
 <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/ontologies/Word"/>
```

Comment: 1. Please proof read your text! It's weird to see so many typos... 2. What means logically connected? By what are the individuals connected such that you think they should also be returned? Show sample data.

Comment: @AKSW Thank you for your reply. Logically means instance are connected with symmetric object property. For example software Design is connected with software development via symmetric object property(isSynonymOf).I can fetch only  software design by object property but can not get software development which aslo has same object property.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `OntModel` doesn't consider apply OWL reasoning ,thus, inference has to be enabled to explicitely to consider symmetric properties:

```
OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);
```

See the [documentation](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/#owl) for more details.

Just a side note, Jena has lots of convenience methods, e.g. your code could be shortened by using

```
model.listSubjectsWithProperty(isSynonymOf)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137282/discussion-on-answer-by-aksw-how-to-extract-the-synonyms-of-a-specific-individua).